# Node C++ Addon How to require js modules?

Tags: node.js

I have a C++ Node.js add-on. I can run use v8's RunScript to run execute javascript in the context of the native module.

Now, I also would like to execute a JS statement that contains require.
Unfortunately, the native module is setup in such a way that the context does not include require. I get the error:

> ReferenceError: require is not defined

Is there a way prepare the native module's context such that it behaves like a standard node.js module ? i.e. it provides the require method?

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same issue, what I have done was adding this be code below, prior loading my addon.

```
global.require = require;
```